# NumPy + PyTorch Tensor assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

lets assume we have a `tensor` representing an image of the shape `(910, 270, 1)` which assigned a number (some index) to each pixel with width=910 and height=270.

We also have a `numpy` array of size `(N, 3)` which maps a 3-tuple to an index.

I now want to create a new numpy array of shape `(920, 270, 3)` which has a 3-tuple based on the original tensor index and the mapping-3-tuple-numpy array. How do I do this assignment without for loops and other consuming iterations?

This would look simething like:

```
color_image = np.zeros((self._w, self._h, 3), dtype=np.int32)
self._colors = np.array(N,3) # this is already present
indexed_image = torch.tensor(920,270,1) # this is already present

#how do I assign it to this numpy array?
color_image[indexed_image.w, indexed_image.h] = self._colors[indexed_image.flatten()]
```

Comment: what is N? You can probably extend it to the size of the image for broadcasting

Comment: @Eumel N is is the count of indexes which are existent. This gets extended during runtime, as more and more indexes get mapped to a color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `_colors`, and `indexed_image`. Something that ressembles to:

```
>>> indexed_image = torch.randint(0, 10, (920, 270, 1))
>>> _colors  = np.random.randint(0, 255, (N, 3))
```

A common way of converting a dense map to a RGB map is to loop over the label set:

```
>>> _colors = torch.FloatTensor(_colors)

>>> rgb = torch.zeros(indexed_image.shape[:-1] + (3,))
>>> for lbl in range(N):
...     rgb[lbl == indexed_image[...,0]] = _colors[lbl]
```

Comment: That's amazing! So `rgb[lbl == indexed_image[...,0]]` is used as "if label is present in the indexed image" then assign a color?

Comment: Have a look at `lbl == indexed_image[...,0]`: it is a mask of the same shape as `indexed_image` containing `1`s where the values of `indexed_image` are equal to label `lbl`. You can use this mask to index `rgb` and ultimately assign `_colors[lbl]` to only that selection.

Comment: Appreciate the help!